# Need to get 2 values from single select value. MySQL, XML in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, forms

i have a select box with these values:

```
<form action="ampcontrols.php" method="post" name="amp">
<select name="amp">
<option value="Fender '57 Deluxe","103">Fender '57 Deluxe</option>
<option value="Fender '59 Bassman","100">Fender '59 Bassman</option>
<option value="Fender '57 Champ","124">Fender '57 Champ</option>
<option value="Fender '65 Deluxe Reverb","83">Fender '65 Deluxe Reverb</option>
<option value="Fender '65 Princeton","106">Fender '65 Princeton</option>
<option value="Fender '65 Twin Reverb","117">Fender '65 Twin Reverb</option>
<option value="Fender Super-Sonic(Burn)","114">Fender Super-Sonic(Burn)</option>
<option value="British '60s","97">British '60s</option>
<option value="British '70s","121">British '70s</option>
<option value="British '80s","94">British '80s</option>
<option value="American '90","93">American '90s</option>
<option value="Metal 2000","109">Metal 2000</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I would like to be able to get 2 values and use them independantly. This is a single select box not multiple.
I can echo the selected name ie Fender '57 Deluxe for an HTML tag no problem, but also need to pass it's corresponding number to be inserted into an xml file seperately. i.e. Select Fender '57 Deluxe as heading and 103 as id for xml.
I've tried with MySQL, XML but can only pass one value at a time!!  I'm probably missing something simple.
Cheers

Comment: You can only have one value, but you could always format is "value-name" and `explode()` it when it's being processed. Everything before the dash will be the ID number, and everything after it is the name.

Comment: Can i use values seperately?

Comment: You can - explode will give you an array with the ID number as the first entry, and the description as the second.

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly give me an example? I have tried explode() but just getting array as the output.

Comment: if you use `$myArray = explode('-', $_REQUEST['amp'])`, then `$myArray[0]` is what you need to access the index number,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is not valid.

To put multiple values on a single option you can use an array or an object

**Example of using an array**

```
<select name="amp">
    <option value='["Fender &apos;57 Deluxe","103"]'>Fender '57 Deluxe</option>
</select>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$amp = json_decode($_POST['amp']);
$amp[0] // Fender '57
$amp[1] // 103
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I must be doing something wrong because all i'm getting are the characters at that index ie [0] returns [ [1]returns ' [3] returns F and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly, each heading is identified by its id, and you have control over the html as well as the processing in PHP. In this case, you don't need to pass the headings back to the PHP processing part; you only need to show them in the HTML so the user can choose "Fender '59 Deluxe" instead of "103".

So, just make sure your PHP knows which id goes with which label, and then you can show the labels to the user and the ids to the PHP/XML.

```
<?php
  // This array would typically be pulled from a database
  $amps = array(
    103 => "Fender '57 Deluxe",
    100 => "Fender '59 Bassman",
    124 => "Fender '57 Champ",
    83 => "Fender '65 Deluxe Reverb",
    106 => "Fender '65 Princeton",
    117 => "Fender '65 Twin Reverb",
    114 => "Fender Super-Sonic(Burn)",
    97 => "British '60s",
    121 => "British '70s",
    94 => "British '80s",
    93 => "American '90",
    109 => "Metal 2000"
  );

  // Check if the form has been submitted
  if (isset($_POST['amp'])) {
    $selected_amp = intval($_POST['amp']);
    if (array_key_exists($selected_amp, $amps)) {
      $label = $amps[$selected_amp];
      insert_xml($selected_amp, $label);
      // (todo: create function insert_xml)
    } else {
      // (todo: error handling)
    }
  }
?>
<form action="ampcontrols.php" method="post" name="amp">
  <select name="amp">
  <?php foreach ($amps as $id => $label): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($label); ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As you can see, I like to use foreach/endforeach for PHP inside HTML; you can use braces if you prefer of course.

Comment: Cheers. How do i echo the label along with it's id to ampcontrols.php.

Comment: Well, is ampcontrols.php the file that prints the form (the one above)? If not, what does it look like?

Comment: Yes it prints the above. I need the id to be saved to an xml file and the label to remind users which amp their editing. The ampcontrols.php file is quite long , there's a form for inputing volume, gain, treble etc values, these are then saved along with the id to the xml file using PHP DOM. That's working but not complete yet. By the way the xml file is used as a preset for Fender Fuse software/amps.

Comment: Well, if you have the `$selected_amp` id, you could echo the label by using `$amps[$selected_amp]`, but somehow I have a feeling that's not what you mean :)

Comment: Thanks for ypur time and input.